# laravel Group by añadiendo un segunda relación

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente inquietud, estoy intentando relación los usuarios dentro de una alianza y grupo a la vez, para lo cual tengo lo siguiente parte

Controlador

```
public function render()
{
    $partys = party::all()->groupby('id_alliance');

    return view('livewire.party-index', compact('partys', 'users'))->extends('layouts.index');
}
```

primero separe las alianza y sus grupos

```
            @foreach ($partys as $id_alliance => $items)
                <h4 class="mt-4">{{ __('web.Alliance') }}
                    {{$id_alliance}}
                </h4>
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach ($items as $item)
                        <div class=" mt-2 col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <h5>{{ $item->nameParties }}</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="m-2">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <h6>{{ $item->leaderParties }}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        USUARIOS RELACIONADOS
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es relacionar los usuarios que pertenece tanto a una alianza y  grupo. lo cual no se como hacer dicha relación

Dejo las tablas para mayor información

Tabla party

```
    $table->id();
    $table->string('nameParties')->nullable();
    $table->integer('amountParties')->nullable();
    $table->string('leaderParties')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_alliance')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_alliance')->references('id')->on('alliances');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Tabla Uusarios

```
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_alliance')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_alliance')->references('id')->on('alliances');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_party')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_party')->references('id')->on('parties');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
```

La tabla de usuario tiene la llave foránea tanto de la party como de la alianza lo cual no se si este bien estructurado

**Posible Solución de emergencia**

Lo que hice para solucionar temporalmente fue, aunque creo que esta mal pero funciona fue agregar esto

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->id_alliance == $item->id_alliance and $user->id_party == $item->id)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

y queda así

```
@foreach ($partys as $id_alliance => $items)
    <h4 class="mt-4">{{ __('web.Alliance') }}
        {{ $id_alliance }}
    </h4>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($items as $item)
            <div class=" mt-2 col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5>{{ $item->nameParties }}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="m-2">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h6>{{ $item->leaderParties }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                @if ($user->id_alliance == $item->id_alliance and $user->id_party == $item->id)
                                    {{ $user->name }}
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Me da el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, puedes explicar un poco más sobre lo que quieres hacer? Tu pregunta no es muy clara

Comment: Por favor mira la posible Posible Solución, lo que quiero es mostrar uan lista de usuarios según a la alianza y el grupo